# Reshape table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `demo` in SQL Server. Below is the code to generate the table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
  Customer INT,
  Year_Month NVARCHAR(255),
  Category CHAR(1),
  A NVARCHAR(255),
  B NVARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO demo
  (Customer, Year_Month, Category, A, B)
VALUES
  (1, '201701', 'A', '1', NULL),
  (1, '201702', 'A', '1', NULL),
  (1, '201703', 'A', '0', NULL),
  (1, '201704', 'A', '1', NULL),
  (1, '201701', 'B', NULL, '0'),
  (1, '201702', 'B', NULL, '1'),
  (1, '201703', 'B', NULL, '1'),
  (2, '201701', 'A', '0', NULL),
  (2, '201702', 'A', '0', NULL),
  (2, '201701', 'B', NULL, '0'),
  (2, '201702', 'B', NULL, '1'),
  (3, '201701', 'A', '1', NULL),
  (3, '201702', 'A', '1', NULL),
  (3, '201703', 'A', '0', NULL),
  (3, '201704', 'A', '0', NULL),
  (3, '201705', 'A', '0', NULL),
  (3, '201706', 'A', '1', NULL),
  (3, '201701', 'B', NULL, '1'),
  (3, '201702', 'B', NULL, '0'),
  (3, '201703', 'B', NULL, '1'),
  (3, '201704', 'B', NULL, '0');
```

Using SQL, I want to restructure the table as shown below:
[image]

What SQL query should I write to get the table shown in the image (to which the arrow is pointing) as the result?

Comment: Have you tried a Self Join?

Comment: @DaleK: I have to write a SQL query to get the table shown in the image (to which the arrow is pointing) as the result.

Comment: I have to ask...why do you have a column that states if the row is either A or B in addition to columns for each category? Why not just have a category column and a value column?

Comment: @SiddharthGosalia thats called a result-set not a table FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select
    Customer,
    Year_Month,
    max(A) as A,
    max(B) as B
From demo
group by Customer, Year_Month
order by Customer, Year_Month
```